# Verify claim: product of exponential expectations

Tags: probability, expected-value

Is it true that:

$$\mathbb{E}[\exp(X)]\mathbb{E}[\exp(-X)] = 1$$

where $X$ is any random variable? We cannot say that $\mathbb{E}[\exp(X)]\mathbb{E}[\exp(-X)]= \mathbb{E}[\exp(X-X)]$ since $X$ and $-X$ are not independent. However if we look at the integrals we have:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}exp(x)f(x)dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}exp(-x)f(-x)d(-x)$$

I am thinking now that we can use Fubini's to conclude that this is equal to

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}exp(x-x)f(x)f(-x)dxd(-x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)f(-x)dxd(-x) = 1$$

What do you think? Thanks!

Comment: Counterexample: Bernoulli 1,-1. Tour mistake is un taking the same variables un Fubini theorem for diferente spaces.

Comment: Careful with those two different integrals! Where you have written $\exp(x - x)$, the two $x$s are different dummy variables. This is why it's usually a good idea not to re-use dummy variables in situations like this. Indeed this is a bit too good to be true. If you can think of a positive-valued random variable $Y$ with $\Bbb E Y \cdot \Bbb E [Y^{-1}] \ne 1$, then its logarithm will be a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at $$\int_\Omega \exp(X)\,d\mathbb P \cdot \int_\Omega \exp(-X)\,d\mathbb P = \int_{\Omega^2} \exp(X(\omega)-X(\nu))\,d\mathbb P^2(\omega,\nu)$$

Now if the $\exp$ wasn’t there we’d argue that the whole thing is symmetric and thus $0$. But as the $\exp$ is here this would require that $\int \exp(...) = \exp(\int ...)$, which is quite unlikely. So let’s try to construct a counterexample (and by the above it should not be hard to find such a thing). So let’s take $X\sim\mathcal U(0,1)$. Then
$$ \int_0^1 \exp(x) \, dx = \exp(1) - \exp(0) = e - 1 $$
meanwhile
$$ \int_{-1}^0 \exp(x) \, dx = \exp(0) - \exp(-1) = 1 - 1/e $$
Clearly we have
$$ \frac{e-1}{1- 1/e} = \frac{e^2-e}{e-1} = e \neq 1$$

EDIT: The mistake in your proof is that you reduce the product measure integral into a single integral with the same variable. It is valid to say
$$ \int f\, dx \int g\, dx = \iint f(x)g(y)\,dx\,dy $$ but you are essentially saying
$$ \int f\, dx \int g\, dx = \int fg\, dx$$
which is not true.

Comment: Thank you and everybody for spotting the flaw :)